# JS: Why does function declaration order matter when inside a conditional block?

Tags: javascript, hoisting

```
a();
function a() {
    $('.doit').text('Text was replaced (a)');   
}

if ($('.doit2').length) {
    b();
    function b() {
         $('.doit2').text('Text was replaced (b)');   
    }
}
```

`a()` is called correctly, while `b` gives an error `"b is not defined"`. Why?

(I've read about hoisting but `function b` is declared, not a variable. Or am I wrong?)

See [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/32cftge3/2/) - Firefox is raising an error, while Chrome works.

Comment: Which browser are you using. It seem to work fine in chrome. [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qyjpwku5/)

Comment: it does not give any error to me and it should not

Comment: Could you create a fiddle to produce this problem? I don't see a problem with this, perhaps the problem is somewhere else in your code? Also could you provide what browser you are using?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23125529/need-to-understand-javascript-function-hoisting-example

Comment: Above code working fine in chrome for me too.

Comment: Guys you rock. My fiddle had an typo so I thought Chrome does give this behavior as well ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By Javascript specs, function declarations are not allowed in conditionals (or any other blocks). Therefore, this is technically undefined behavior. Some browsers attempt to create a reasonable behavior. However, you shouldn't rely on browsers being able to interpret this correctly.

> FunctionDeclarations are only allowed to appear in Program or
>   FunctionBody. Syntactically, they can not appear in Block ({ ... }) —
>   such as that of if, while or for statements.

http://kangax.github.io/nfe/#function-declarations-in-blocks